# Can't mount volume in Docker Compose right

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, volume, mount

Firstly, I went all that step by step: https://docs.docker.com/language/golang/develop/
Works perfectly.
Then I started to try the same with my golang project. It requires not only db in a volume but also 'assets' and 'creds' directories which I was able to provide working with normal Dockerfile and --mount flag in 'docker run' comand.
So my schema was:

- Create a volume 'roach'.
- Create a temp container for copying folders.

```
    docker container create --name temp -v roach:/data busybox \
    docker cp assets/ temp:/data \
    docker rm temp
```

- Run my container with

```
docker run -it --rm \
  --mount 'type=volume,src=roach,dst=/usr/data' \
  --network mynet \
  --name postgres-server \
  -p 80:8080 \
  -e PGUSER=totoro \
  -e PGPASSWORD=myfriend \
  -e PGHOST=db \
  -e PGPORT=26257 \
  -e PGDATABASE=mydb \
 postgres-server
```

- Go files have acces to `/usr/data/my_folders`

BTW here is Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM golang:1.18-buster AS build

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod .
RUN go mod download

COPY . .

RUN go mod tidy

RUN go build -o /t main/main.go main/inst_list.go


## Deploy

FROM gcr.io/distroless/base-debian10

ENV GO111MODULE=on
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='/usr/data/credentials/creds.json'

WORKDIR /

COPY --from=build /t /t

EXPOSE 8080

USER root:root


ENTRYPOINT ["/t"]
```

================================================================

Then I started to try to make a Docker-compose.yml file like in the end of that example.
It has no --mount flags but I found plenty ways to specify mount path.
I tried much more but left 3 variants of it in code bellow(2 of 3 are commented):

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  docker-t-roach:
    depends_on: 
      - roach
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: postgres-server
    hostname: postgres-server
    networks:
      - mynet
    ports:
      - 80:8080
    environment:
      - PGUSER=${PGUSER:-totoro}
      - PGPASSWORD=${PGPASSWORD:?database password not set}
      - PGHOST=${PGHOST:-db}
      - PGPORT=${PGPORT:-26257}
      - PGDATABASE=${PGDATABASE-mydb}
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
  roach:
    image: cockroachdb/cockroach:latest-v20.1
    container_name: roach
    hostname: db
    networks:
      - mynet
    ports:
      - 26257:26257
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
#      - type: volume
#        source: roach
#        target: /usr/data
      
      - roach:/usr/data
        
#     - "${PWD}/cockroach-data/roach:/usr/data"
    command: start-single-node --insecure

volumes:
  roach:


networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge
```

and it still doesn't work. Moreover it creates 2 Volumes: 'roach' and 'WORKDIRNAME_roach'. I actually tried to copy my folders to both of those. It's not working. The output of build command is alwaysl like that:

```
postgres-server   | STARTED AT
postgres-server   | Sep  4 10:43:10
postgres-server   | lstat /usr/data/assets/current_batch: no such file or directory
postgres-server   | 2022/09/04 10:43:10 lstat /usr/data/assets/current_batch: no such file or directory
```

(first 2 strings are produced my my go.files, 'assets' is the folder I'm copying)
I think that I'm seaking in the wrong place: maybe the way I copy folders doesn't work with this kind of build?

UPDATE:
At the same time command

```
docker run -it --rm -v roach:/data ubuntu ls /data/usr
```

showes that my folders are there. But container is in kind of cycle that doesn't let him see them.

Comment: there is no volume mount on `postgres-server` service. If you copy the `assets` folder at build time (in Dockerfile) can you post your Dockerfile?

Comment: Dockerfile is like this: `# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1 

FROM golang:1.18-buster AS build 

WORKDIR /app 

COPY go.mod . 
RUN go mod download 

COPY . . 

RUN go mod tidy 

RUN go build -o /t main/main.go main/inst_list.go 


## Deploy 

FROM gcr.io/distroless/base-debian10 

ENV GO111MODULE=on 
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='/usr/data/credentials/creds.json'

WORKDIR / 

COPY --from=build /t /t 

EXPOSE 8080`

Comment: When I used only Dockerfile I ran command: `docker run -it --rm \
  --mount 'type=volume,src=roach,dst=/usr/data' \
  --network mynet \
  --name postgres-server \
  -p 80:8080 \
  -e PGUSER=totoro \
  -e PGPASSWORD=myfriend \
  -e PGHOST=db \
  -e PGPORT=26257 \
  -e PGDATABASE=mydb \
 docker-t-roach`

Comment: So you do need to map a local folder into `/usr/data` in the container. Has to be the folder that contains `credentials` and `assets`

Comment: yes, as I wrote in subject

Comment: but I need an access to it from outside. that's why I'm trying to make it through named volume.

Comment: At the same time command
```docker run -it --rm -v roach:/data ubuntu ls /data/usr ```
showes that my folders are there. But container is in kind of cycle that doesn't let him see them.

Comment: If this last command does shows files then that's your problem. `/data/usr` vs `/usr/data`. And you can access folders from outside as well, not only named volumes. and again, you are mounting the volumes on the wrong service. once you understand this you will also make some progress. the service `docker-t-roach` needs volumes, not the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Mihai is tried to help but I didn't understand what he meant. He actually meant that I had to add volume to my app service. I did it now and it works. In example bellow I named 2 volumes for db and app different just for better accuracy:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  docker-parser:
    depends_on: 
      - roach
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: parser
    hostname: parser
    networks:
      - mynet
    ports:
      - 80:8080
    volumes:
      - assets:/data
    environment:
      - PGUSER=${PGUSER:-totoro}
      - PGPASSWORD=${PGPASSWORD:?database password not set}
      - PGHOST=${PGHOST:-db}
      - PGPORT=${PGPORT:-26257}
      - PGDATABASE=${PGDATABASE-mydb}
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
  roach:
    image: cockroachdb/cockroach:latest-v20.1
    container_name: roach
    hostname: db
    networks:
      - mynet
    ports:
      - 26257:26257
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - roach:/db
    command: start-single-node --insecure

volumes:
  assets:
  roach:

networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge
```